# merge two array result wrong array which contain second array as array rather a complete of both

Tags: php

I tries to array_merge in php but resultant array is not correct

```
1. Array ( [id] => 12 [name] => Popular ) 
2. Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => Flowers ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 10 [name] => Chocolates ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 11 [name] => Sweets and Dry Fruits ) )
```

Resultant Array

```
Array ( [id] => 12 [name] => Popular [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => Flowers ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 10 [name] => Chocolates ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 11 [name] => Sweets and Dry Fruits ) )
```

Comment: It seems correct to me. Why are you saying it's not?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the new data in the same format as the existing data then use `[]` rather than `array_merge()`.

```
$array1 = array( 'id' => 12, 'name' => 'Popular');
$array2 = array(array( 'id' => 8, 'name' => 'Flowers'),
    array( 'id' => 10, 'name' => 'Chocolates'),
    array( 'id' => 11, 'name' => 'Sweets and Dry Fruits')
);

$array2[] = $array1;
print_r($array2);
```

outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => Flowers
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => Chocolates
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Sweets and Dry Fruits
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Popular
        )

)
```

If you want the data to be at the front, then you need to create an array of that data and then use `array_merge()`...

```
$array3 = array_merge(array($array1), $array2);
print_r( $array3);
```

Comment: Add want array 1 be the first element of the resultant array